# ngrx updating state from effects

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, interceptor, ngrx-effects

I have ngrx store setup that stores currently active user and user's locale. Based on user locale my interceptor will inject **X-LOCALE** header in all API calls. When action to select user is called I first call separate API to get locale for that user, pass that locale to interceptor and then proceed on calling rest of APIs (at this point X-LOCALE header should be injected). Question: how do I trigger change of the state from user-effects.ts?

**user-reducer.ts**

```
export interface UsersState extends EntityState<UserInfo> {
  loading: boolean;
  currentUser: UserInfo;
  locale: string;
}
const usersReducer = createReducer(
  INITIAL_STATE,
  on(actions.fetchUser, 
  ...bunch of other actions...,
  (state) => ({ ...state, loading: true })
);
```

**user-actions.ts**

```
...bunch of actions
export const fetchUser = createAction('[USERS] Fetch User Request', props<{ uuid: string }>());
```

**user-effects.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersEffects {
  fetchUser$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(usersActions.fetchUser),
      switchMap(({ uuid }) => {
        // here we would read user locale
        return this.usersService.fetchUserLocale(uuid).pipe(
          map((locale) => {
            // ******* here i need to update locale in the state ********
            return uuid;
          });
        }),
      );
    }),
    switchMap((uuid) => {
      // all calls from here on should have "X-LOCALE" header injected
      return forkJoin([
        this.usersService.fetchUser(uuid),
        this.usersService.fetchUserCards(uuid),
        this.usersService.fetchUserPermissions(uuid),
      ]).pipe(
        map(([userDto, cards, permissions]) => {
          const userInfo = { ...userDto, cards, permissions };
          return usersActions.fetchUserSuccess({ userInfo });
        }),
        catchError((error) => of(usersActions.fetchUserFailure({ error }))),
      );
    }),
  ),
);
```

and here **locale.interceptor.ts** that would inject headers

```
@Injectable()
  export class HttpHeadersInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private store$: Store<UsersState>) {
      this.store$.pipe(select((state) => state.locale)).subscribe((locale: string) => {
        this.locale = locale;
      });
    }
    private locale: string;

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      const defaultHeaders = { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain' };

      if (this.locale) {
        defaultHeaders['X-LOCALE'] = this.locale;
      }

      const authReq = req.clone({ setHeaders: defaultHeaders });

      return next.handle(authReq);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'm not sure if it's a best practice, but you still can dispatch an action from within the `switchMap`, be it directly from the `map` or you can change it to `tap` since there's no actual mapping, it's just a side effect. Something like this.

```
  switchMap(({ uuid }) => {
    // here we would read user locale
    return this.usersService.fetchUserLocale(uuid).pipe(
      tap((locale) => {
        this.store.dispatch(desiredAction({ uuid }));
      });
    }),
  );
```

As I said, I'm not sure if this is the best practice but in my project I used something similar on couple of occasions.

Comment: I see. Better then nothing. Thank you!